# How to change between the two languages ​in my navigation with VUE.JS and JSS Sitecore?

Tags: jss

I want to create a multilingual site with vue.js and JSS, I added in the folder **data/route/en.json and fr.json**, I don't know how to change between the two languages ​​in my navigation.

Answer (score 1):

The out of the box Vue sample routing does not support language-path based routing. I would suggest reviewing the router setup in the React or Angular advanced apps, which support language-prefix based paths, and translating that to Vue. We are planning to ship with universal support for language path based routing in the next tech preview.